# Records are sorted in SQL Server, but when brought to MS Access subform, the sorting is different

Tags: sql-server, sorting, ms-access, vba, ms-access-2013

My query in SQL Server is sorted by several factors, and when I execute it the ordering is all correct. I have some subforms that are populated using the following code:

```
Set db = OpenDatabase("", False, False, globalstrSQLConnection)
strSQL = "SELECT * FROM qryTaskSimple"
Set rs = db.OpenRecordset(strSQL, dbOpenSnapshot, dbSeeChanges)
Set Me.Recordset = rs
```

where `globalstrSQLConnection` is the connection to the database on my my SQL Server and `qryTaskSimple` is the query mentioned above. But the subforms are sorted by a completely different criterion. Instead of being sorted by:

```
ORDER BY CASE WHEN tblTask.JobNum LIKE '***FULL***' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END, DivisionSortID, SuperintendentSortID, ISNULL(dbo.tblTask.Ordering, 999999999), 
                     dbo.tblTask.JobNum, dbo.tblTask.Sequence
```

as stated inside the query, it seems to be sorted by only `tblTask.JobNum`... even when I replace the entire `ORDER BY` clause with `ORDER BY DivisionSortID`... And I don't have any VBA code that further sorts the subforms.

Comment: If you don't have an order by on your query there is no way to ensure the order. Add that order by to your query.

Comment: So even though qryTaskSimple already has the ORDER BY clause, it needs to be explicitly stated in strSQL? When I add it so it says `strSQL = "SELECT * FROM qryTaskSimple " & vbCrLf & "ORDER BY CASE WHEN tblTask.JobNum LIKE '***FULL***' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END, DivisionSortID, SuperintendentSortID, ISNULL(dbo.tblTask.Ordering, 999999999), dbo.tblTask.JobNum , dbo.tblTask.Sequence"
`, I get 
`Run-time error '3075': Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression` when trying to run it

Comment: you're probably getting errors because  you are referring to the underlying tables instead of to the query. Refer to the query's name and col names instead of to the underlying table(s) names and col names because at this point the query is a 'table'. Instead of all that, you might want to just copy the querie's SQL into the subform's recordset if that's an option.

Comment: Well you were partially right, but now the error is highlighting `CASE WHEN JobNum LIKE '***FULL***' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END`

Comment: To elaborate on the 'object based sort over-ride' thing. If you right click on a column while viewing data in a table/query/continuous forms/etc and choose sort A to Z for example, that sort will over-ride any original sorting. Sometimes that order by can get 'stuck' in the object's data properties which can be confusing. Another somewhat related PITA is how you can drag a query's columns to different locations in datasheet view so they are out of sync with design view. 2 order bys, 2 column orders..1 SQL based, 1 object based

Comment: CASE WHEN; no clue what your original tables or orginal SQL looks like, but if JobNum col is not included as a column in qryTaskSimple, the sort won't find it. Add JobNum as a column in org query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Queries and tables in Access have an underlying query/table object `order by` that can over-ride the SQL `order by`. You can see it (and remove it) in respective object properties.

It can be pretty frustrating and I'm not really sure if that's what's going on, but regardless, you can force desired sorting by simply adding it to your SQL statement, treating the query as a table.

```
strSQL = "SELECT * FROM qryTaskSimple ORDER BY <your desired sorting using any qryTaskSimple cols>"
```

if that doesn't work, then try the (sub)forms orderby at the form's load() event:

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
   me.orderby = "your order by statements"
   if me.orderbyon = false then me.orderbyon = true
End Sub
```

Comment: Adding ORDER BY [...] still gets me an error (in the comments in my main post). Ideally I would have it sorted on SQL Server for faster load time, but thanks for that suggestion. I will use it as a last resort.

Comment: If JobNum col is not included as a column in qryTaskSimple, the sort won't find it. Add JobNum as a column in org query. SQL Server would be faster but it looks like you have Access to deal with afterward. As a final thought, why not take care of the complicated sort criteria at SQL Server level by creating a view with aliased cols for CASE and ISNULL so Access sorting will be more basic. Good Luck and have a nice weekend.

Comment: JobNum is there, as are all the other ORDER BY fields. Creating an alias for the sort columns is a good idea though

Comment: So creating the aliases and changing it to `ORDER BY orderbyFullTask, DivisionSortID, SuperintendentSortID, orderbyOrdering, JobNum, Sequence` solves the issue. it SEEMS like Access can't handle passing Transact-SQL through one of their functions, even though SQL Server is the one interpreting it... hmm.